# Comparing numerical results with different integration grids sizes (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, grid, numerical-integration

I am trying to compare the numerical results of a complex integral using Matlab's `integral`.

In particular, I want to examine the accuracy of the results using

- a fixed integration interval [0,T],
- but different sparseness or integration grid sizes.

Is there a way to specify integration grid sizes (i.e.: number of equally spaced grid points) when using Matlab's `integral`? Or should I find other alternatives?

Comment: Sounds to me like you should roll your own numerical integration algorithm. It's not hard to write something basic. For right Riemann sum, `x = linspace(T/n,T,n)'; y = f(x); dx = T/n; my_integral = sum(y * dx)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify integration grid sizes (i.e.: number of equally spaced grid points) when using MATLAB's `integral`?

Short answer: No.

The [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) says you can enter only:

> `q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax,Name,Value)` specifies additional options with one or more Name,Value pair arguments. For example, specify `'WayPoints'` followed by a vector of real or complex numbers to indicate specific points for the integrator to use.

So, we scroll down a bit and read which name/value pairs are allowed and find:

- `'AbsTol'`, absolute error tolerance
- `'RelTol'`, relative error tolerance
- `'ArrayValued'`, array-valued function flag
- `'Waypoints'`, integration waypoints

MATLAB automatically optimises the integral and computes in numerically (of course), which ends for a given error, defined by `'AbsTol'` and `'RelTol'`. I'd just go with that.

If you do want to specify integration step size you can check what happens if you specify `'Waypoints'` to be `[0:1/(100*T):T]`. I'd go with integrating it myself though, using a simple Riemann sum implementation.